# Python set comparison is operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I am trying to compare two sets

```
#logical operators

set1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

set2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

# is operator
is_set1_set2_same = set1 is set2

print(is_set1_set2_same)
```

This result is as expected "`False`"

```
set2.remove(7)
is_set1_set2_same = set1 is set2

print(is_set1_set2_same)
```

**Question** : I was expecting the output of this one should be "True", but i see its "False" , When I print two sets i see exactly same. Please let me know if i am missing something here on sets.

```
set3 = set1

is_set1_set3_same =  set1 is set3

print(is_set1_set3_same)
```

This results as expected "`True`"

Comment: You should compare with `==` not with `is`.

Comment: `is` matches the reference (address) of the set objects, use `==` instead.

Comment: You should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is

Comment: Thanks , it works as expected with == operator .

Answer (score 1):

`is` is not a `set` operator - it is an operator for object references.

`set3 = set1` will be making the `set3` object reference the same as object `set1`, therefore `is` will be `True` always, regardless of the type of object.

---

To compare set equality, you must check if they [are proper subsets of one another](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset)

```
sets_same = (set1 <= set2) and (set2 <= set1)
```